# UICollectionView in ios 5

Tags: ios5, ios6

I just learned about UICollectionView after creating the same functionality in a custom class. So I am thinking about using deleting all that code I wrote and just using UICollectionView.

I know my app gets a lot of installs on iOS 5. And I know a lot non tech savvy friends and family still have it installed.

I googled this and it says I can use some other's guys library(another thing I should have known before writing my custom class). But the answer was not definitive.

So my question is, does Apple include a bridge for iOS 5 or will my app just fail if I use UICollectionView?

I have my target deployment set to 5.0 and it is not giving me any warnings.

Venkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is iOS6 only. You can include extra code to check for iOS6 and use your custom class on iOS5. But there is no way to use an actual `UICollectionView` in iOS5.'

Thats what that "other guy's library" does. It has an iOS5 compliant clone of `UICollectionView` and checks based on the OS which to use.

Comment: so what would happen if a user with ios 5 gets my app?

Comment: If you haven't done some `if:else` style checking, it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try this as an alternative: 
https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView